# MySQL Lock Taking AGES To Select

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, transactions

I have a fairly big table that has 150 individual PHP scripts connect, select data to process, update as `in_use`, then process.

So that no script selects the same data as another in the same session, `in_use` is set, and a transaction lock is used to ensure no script selects the same data as another. Here is the code (in PHP):

```
$sql - "select data....FOR UPDATE;" // <-- real query is much longer and not really neccesary here.

mysqli_autocommit($db_connect, FALSE);
mysqli_begin_transaction($db_connect, MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE);
$b = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql);
$to_process = mysqli_fetch_all($b, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$s = "'" . implode("', '", $to_process) . "'";
mysqli_query($db_connect, "UPDATE `users` SET `in_use` = 1 WHERE `username` IN ({$s});");
mysqli_commit($db_connect);
```

The issue is that each select, which takes seconds when done manually, takes like 10 minutes between each of the 150 queries (meaning 1500 mins in total just selecting data). Is there a frequency variable that `MySQL` uses to see when to check when the lock should be free? I really need to speed this up as each `SELECT` query should only take seconds between each other.

Thanks all!

EDIT

The query is :

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT `username` 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `in_use` = 0 
  AND `username_from` IN 
      ( SELECT DISTINCT `username` 
        FROM `source_accounts` 
        WHERE `group_users` = '{$owner['group_users']}' 
          AND (`type` = 'users' OR `type` = 'both') 
          AND `use` = '1'
      ) 
   AND `username` NOT IN 
      ( SELECT `user_request` 
        FROM `request_history` 
        WHERE `owner_account` = '{$owner['username']}'
      ) 
   LIMIT {$owner['follow']} FOR UPDATE;
```

Comment: Use InnoDB storage engine which is more faster and don't have to wait a specific query to be completed to continue.

Comment: Do you have any triggers?

Comment: @RedAcid SELECT..FOR UPDATE is InnoDB

Comment: first of all use InnoDB like @RedAcid said and also if there is no you should add some indexes to your table for key coloumns which are used in the where clouses

Comment: I am using InnoDB and use index's. Like I said, the queries select quickly when done manually and outside of a transaction. No @Mihai I am not using any triggers at the moment.

Comment: How many usernames are selected per query? Remember that WHERE ... IN can be very slow with large set of items. You can try to set your buffer size higher to improve the speed of queries.

Comment: I think the full query may in fact be very relevant. As you may be attempting to set locks on rows in many tables. Lets see it.

Comment: Sure @RiggsFolly     `SELECT DISTINCT username FROM `users` WHERE `in_use` = 0 AND username_from IN (SELECT DISTINCT `username` FROM source_accounts WHERE group_users = '{$owner['group_users']}' AND (`type` = 'users' OR `type` = 'both') AND `use` = '1') AND username NOT IN (SELECT user_request FROM `request_history` WHERE owner_account = '{$owner['username']}') LIMIT {$owner['follow']} FOR UPDATE;`

Comment: Well I would start by using JOIN in that query rather than all those subselects

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments @JohnCliven. Edit your original post to include any new or relevant information.

Comment: Sorry about the code comments, I will do this in the future. @RiggsFolly I'm not great at writing queries and not sure about using JOIN, how much would it reduce the query time by do you reckon?